# lazy loading slick carousel slides on 'beforeChange' event instead of using a url to image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, carousel, lazy-loading, slick.js

I want to use the slick js carousel to lazy load images in a carousel but I don't store my images as url accessible, I'm currently building a ASP.Net MVC site and all my images are stored in the db as byte[]. ex. profile images

I see that for lazy loading in slick you need to do something like this

```js
<img data-lazy="img/lazyfonz1.png"/>

$('.lazy').slick({
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

and I assume the path in the 'data-lazy' attribute is the path that go's to some url?

Is there a different way to get the images without providing a url like the example shows, and maybe other data, while still lazy loading them?

The only idea I had was to use the 'beforeChange' slick event, look at the next slide (which would be empty or have no value in the img src) and do a ajax post call to get the image and return it! This would then be done on every slide change.

Any other ideas or solutions out there that might be better I'm all ears!

Comment: What's the problem with using it the way the example shows?